# Spring get value from applicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to get the value of `@Value("${myVar}")` from `ApplicationContext`. How to do it? Using Spring 5.3.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the value of a property using the Environment API:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
var x = env.getProperty("myVar");
```

You can also get the `Environment` from `ConfigurableApplicationContext`.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html